# No such widget `previous-history`

Tags: terminal, sbt, zsh

I'm setting up a new environment and seem to be experiencing an issue either with SBT or my shell on Linux where hitting the Up arrow instead of showing my previously run command, it says:

> No such widget `previous-history`

I'm using ZSH as the shell, but I'm not seeing this problem anywhere else, including `sbt console`. I assumed there was a bindkey configured that was causing this, but I can't seem to find anything set. This also happens in Bash.

Here is the output I see from `zsh --sourcetrace`:

```
+/etc/zshenv:1> <sourcetrace>
+/etc/zshrc:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.zshrc:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.cache/p10k-instant-prompt-mhicks.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>

[WARNING]: Console output during zsh initialization detected.

When using Powerlevel10k with instant prompt, console output during zsh
initialization may indicate issues.

You can:

  - Recommended: Change ~/.zshrc so that it does not perform console I/O
    after the instant prompt preamble. See the link below for details.

    * You will not see this error message again.
    * Zsh will start quickly and prompt will update smoothly.

  - Suppress this warning either by running p10k configure or by manually
    defining the following parameter:

      typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT=quiet

    * You will not see this error message again.
    * Zsh will start quickly but prompt will jump down after initialization.

  - Disable instant prompt either by running p10k configure or by manually
    defining the following parameter:

      typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT=off

    * You will not see this error message again.
    * Zsh will start slowly.

  - Do nothing.

    * You will see this error message every time you start zsh.
    * Zsh will start quickly but prompt will jump down after initialization.

For details, see:
https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#instant-prompt

-- console output produced during zsh initialization follows --

+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/powerlevel10k/gitstatus/gitstatus.plugin.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/tools/check_for_upgrade.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/cache/.zsh-update:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/compfix.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/bzr.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/clipboard.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/cli.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/compfix.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/completion.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/correction.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/diagnostics.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/directories.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/functions.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/git.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/grep.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/cache/grep-alias:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/history.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/key-bindings.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/misc.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/nvm.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/prompt_info_functions.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/spectrum.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/termsupport.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/custom/example.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/powerlevel10k/internal/p10k.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/powerlevel10k/internal/configure.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/powerlevel10k/internal/worker.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/powerlevel10k/internal/parser.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/powerlevel10k/internal/icons.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/etc/config:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/etc/config:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/etc/config:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-version.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-update.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-config.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-help.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-cache.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-broadcast.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-install.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-availability.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-upgrade.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-env-helpers.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-utils.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-uninstall.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-offline.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-use.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-selfupdate.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-list.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-current.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-main.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-home.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-default.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-env.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-flush.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.sdkman/src/sdkman-path-helpers.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.nvm/nvm.sh:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.nvm/bash_completion:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.zcompdump:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/mhicks/.p10k.zsh:1> <sourcetrace>
```

EDIT: Confirmed, this does happen in Bash, so I figured wiping my user directory completely and starting over might fix it. Alas, it would seem something I'm doing is causing this to persist, or it's some sort of service running. I created a new home directory, installed ohmyzsh, configured powerlevel10k, installed sdkman, installed SBT, installed Java, and then verified this is still happening.

Comment: Could be a _readline_ issue. Do you have a `~/.inputrc`?

Comment: @user1934428, no, I don't.

Comment: @user1934428 Zsh does not use `readline`.

Comment: @darkfrog I doubt the exact same thing happens in `bash`. :) Please update your answer with what output you see in `bash` for your problem.

Comment: @MarlonRichert, I am seeing the same in `bash`, I just confirmed again to make you happy. :)

Comment: This is weird. Hence it depends on something both shells have in common. How about other shells, or other terminal programs? What environment (terminal, operating system) are you using?

Comment: @darkfrog What I meant to ask is: Can you please add to your question, what output you get **from `bash`** when you encounter this problem? It cannot be the same. `bash` has different error messages for these kind of things.

Comment: @MarlonRichert, the reason I didn't add anything explicitly for `bash` is that it is the exact same message.

Comment: @darkfrog Are you sure that it’s bash? I’m unable to produce any error like that on bash. When you’re in bash, what output do you get from `echo $SHELL; $SHELL --version`?

Comment: @MarlonRichert : A more reliable way to get the bash version of the current shell is `echo $BASH_VERSION`, because _SHELL_ may contain incorrect information.

Comment: @user1934428 Why would `$SHELL` contain incorrect information?

Answer (score 0):

The output you're seeing in Zsh means that you <kbd>↑</kbd> key is bound to a non-existing widget. You can very this as follows:

1. Type `bindkey '`.
2. Press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>↑</kbd>.
4. Type `'` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You should now see *one* of the following two cases in your terminal (with `%` being the prompt):

```bash
% bindkey '^[[A'
bindkey '^[[A' previous-history
%
```

```bash
% bindkey '^[OA'
bindkey '^[OA' previous-history
%
```

Although there is a `readline` commands called `previous-history`, there is [no widget by that name in Zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#History-Control). You apparently somewhere in your dotfiles have code that tries to bind <kbd>↑</kbd> to `previous-history`, but fails to actually create the `previous-history` widget. Perhaps you are trying to use `bash` code in your `zsh` dotfiles?

Whatever the case, you can fix this by adding *one* of the following snippets to your `.zshrc`

```bash
bindkey -d  # Delete existing keymaps and reset to default state.
```

```bash
bindkey '^[[A' up-line-or-search
bindkey '^[[B' down-line-or-search
```

```bash
bindkey '^[OA' up-line-or-search
bindkey '^[OB' down-line-or-search
```

Comment: For '^[OA' I get: `"^[OA" up-line-or-beginning-search`, for '^[[A' I get `"^[[A" up-history`. I assume that using `bindkey -d` in the terminal would delete existing keymaps for the current session, right? When I do that, it still doesn't resolve the 'previous-history' issue I'm seeing.

Comment: @MarlonRichrert : This does not explain the effect the OP sees in bash.

Comment: @user1934428 OP hasn’t actually specified what they see in `bash`.

Comment: @darkfrog And what do you see when you press Ctrl-V + ⬆️?

Comment: @MarlonRichert : Unfortunately only in a comment (which of course is bad practice), but he claims that bash would exhibit the same behaviour. I also don't quite understand why he mentions `sbt console`....

Comment: @user1934428 It's impossible that they see _the same_ in bash. In bash, if you `bind` a keycode to a non-existing command, it just does nothing. And if you explicitly call `readline` to run a non-existing command, you get `bash: readline: command not found`. Bash does not use the word "widget" anywhere. That's a ZLE-specific thing.

Comment: On ZSH I see `^[OA` and on Bash I see `^[[A`, but I am seeing the same error message in both Bash and ZSH. It makes me believe something else is running causing this to happen.

Comment: “It makes me believe something else is running causing this to happen.” That sounds likely, yes.

Comment: @darkfrog Start your shell with `zsh --sourcetrace` and you'll get to see exactly which files it sources. Add this to your question.

Comment: @MarlonRichert : Your argument sounds reasonable. I think unless the OP adds more information (including - in this case - a screenshot which supports his claim), there can't be done much more for this case.

Comment: I've added additional information to the original post as well as confirming this is indeed occurring when using only bash. If necessary I can provide a screenshot if you refuse to believe me, but I echoed `$SHELL` showing `/usr/bin/bash` and confirmed this was still occurring.

Comment: Had the issue on ohmyzsh, which brought me here. Added the two downward keys and it worked, removing the issue.

Comment: @darkfrog The value of `$SHELL` doesn’t tell you which shell you are in; it merely tells you what’s your login shell. To see if you’re in Zsh, type `typeset -p ZSH_VERSION`. If you are in Zsh, it will show you which version of Zsh you are running. If not, then you’re in another shell.